# How to make image overlay on underline Please refer the image

Tags: html, css, overlay

**I have this image I want to achieve below using CSS and html i want an image overlaying underline, the image is generated using MS word**
[image: Image that is coming as Base64]

Please help me out Thank you in advance

I have tried this
Could not post the whole base64 due to limitation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Signature Overlay</title>
    <style>
        /* styles.css */
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.signature-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.signature-container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.underline {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000; /* Change this to your preferred underline color */
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="signature-container">
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4>
        <div class="underline"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just increase the `bottom` value of `.underline` a bit ...?

Comment: tried not working

Comment: Please go read [ask]. "Not working" does not work for us, as a proper problem description. You need to properly explain how exactly this is not behaving the way you want.

Comment: Replaced your missing base64 encoded image with one loaded from a placeholder service here, and it appears to be working quite fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jx09kycb/

Comment: yeah..sorry my bad i was trying without the px now it is working thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the bottom like this:

```css
.underline {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```